# C# monitor external process state

Tags: c#, events, process

I am making a launcher app in C# on windows. However the process isn't directly started by my C# application but it uses a url to start it e.g "steam://rungameid/xxxxxxx"

I need it to monitor a process by name (say XYZ.exe) in the following fashion:

Receive an event when XYZ.exe starts
Receive an event when XYZ.exe exits

I just want to minimise and restore the my C# application's form when the application is running and not running respectively

thanks

Comment: This is a little too broad.  Do you have a more-specific question?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a timer (with your preferred timer method) and poll every 'n' milliseconds (find what's best for you... I'd say for minimizing/restoring from a game, 500 milliseconds could be a good start, but experiment), then you can use something like:

```
 bool processRunning = false;

 void timerTickMethod()
 {
    var procIsRunning = Process.GetProcessesByName("xyz.exe").Any();

    if(procIsRunning && !processRunning)
      ProcessIsStartedEvent(); // or directly minimize your app
    else if(!procIsRuning && processRunning)
      ProcessIsEndedEvent(); // or directly restore your app

    processRunning = procIsRunning;
 }
```

If you want to make sure it's *your* `xyz.exe` that is running, you can pass in the full path to `GetProcessesByName` (so that if there's other `xyz.exe` in your system, it won't confuse your app)

#### Update

I was writing from memory, so maybe `GetProcessesByName` only work for friendly names (with no exe, or path).

If that's the case (I haven't tried), and you need the full path you could do it like:

```
var procIsRunning = Process.GetProcesses().Any(x => x.MainModule.Filename == @"c:\your\full\path.exe");
```

Comment: seems legit, gonna give it a try

Comment: that worked although please make few corrections GetProcessesByName looks up process without extension i.e it will work for GetProcessesByName("xyz") and not GetProcessesByName("xyz.exe")
  Secondly for some reason Any() isnt defined for Process[] array , rest the logic works

Comment: `GetProcessesByName` should work with both exe, and no exe (I haven't checked, but I remember so)... and should work with full paths. For `Any()` you need `using System.Linq;` on top.

Comment: I've updated the answer just in case it didn't work (I recall it working but I may be wrong)