# How to execute code once something happens

Tags: c#

I am really bad at explaining, but what I want to do is make it so my program closes once it detects that another program closes.

I was thinking making a while statement, like:

```
   Process thisProc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
   while(IsProcessOpen("chrome.exe") == false)
   this.Close();
```

but then I notice that it was a "while", not something that detects once it happens, it executes the code once, and the code above would execute it while my chrome is closed.

I also want to know how to open chrome when this is open when something is selected, such as

```
   while(button4.Backcolor == Color.Lime); --acts like a checkbox
   Process.Start("Chrome.exe");
```

However, I do not want the Backcolor to change to red once Chrome opens
Also, this method will keep opening chrome while the backcolor is lime(acts as a signal)

Comment: Use the exit event: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9432911/3165499

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629764/c-sharp-monitor-external-process-state

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# detect process exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432870/c-sharp-detect-process-exit)

Comment: _"However, I do not want the Backcolor to change to red once Chrome opens"_ - huh? There's no evidence that such a thing will happen.

Comment: think about events or tasks

Comment: ipinak I want to make it so it executes the code once |||
John, someone told me to use the color of a button as a custom checkbox, and said I should use it to trigger whether or not the code executes, but I want it so it is always on

Answer (score 0):

you have to add some dummy after the while command, like this

```
Process thisProc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
while(IsProcessOpen("chrome.exe") == false)
{
}
this.Close();
```

Comment: the {} do nothing, but they protect this.Close() from being executed DURING the while loop. a different Possibility would be to write ; after the while loop.